# Get title from YouTube videos

Tags: youtube

I want to extract the **Title** of YouTube's videos. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: every time when u open the youtube it shows a title below the title the video is embed

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api

Answer (score 70):

Easiest way to obtain information about a youtube video afaik is to parse the string retrieved from: http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=XXXXXXXX

Using something like PHP's [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), you can obtain a nice array of nearly anything about the video:

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=".$id);
parse_str($content, $ytarr);
echo $ytarr['title'];
```

That will print the title for the video using $id as the video's id.

Comment: This method is very convenient. Is there any official documentation on this method? Thanks.

Comment: There isn't as far as I can tell, which leads me to believe it may not actually be _the best_ method, since the get_video_info could very well die just like get_video did. However, using this method you can access some info not provided in official API (such as direct stream URL for downloading Youtube videos, like get_video provided). Short solution: If official Youtube API (like Alex.Bullard answered here) doesn't provide the desired information, try probing get_video_info

Comment: helped me today :) +1

Comment: Returns 410 NoLongerAvailableException now

Comment: I just tried with one video ID and it still worked for me: http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=dDEtGLQLEi8

However, it's very possible Youtube is phasing this out. I believe they would favor usage of official API.

Comment: Worked for my Extension - Thank You!

Comment: This should really be done over https://. They redirect you there anyway

Comment: @black_belt I know your comment is quite old and you may have realized this by now, but it is quite possible the OP wasn't designing for a page with PHP access.

Comment: just after parse_str() 
we need : 
$jsondec = json_decode($ytarr['player_response'],true);
echo $jsondec['videoDetails'][title];

I have edited the answer.

Comment: @SunilKumar what happened to your edit? Can't see it in the history either.

Comment: @Sz. I am not sure.

Comment: Is this out of date? That url now gives a 410, moved or deleted.

Answer (score 14):

Hello In **python3** i founded 2 ways

**1) without API KEY**

```
import urllib.request
import json
import urllib
import pprint

#change to yours VideoID or change url inparams
VideoID = "SZj6rAYkYOg" 

params = {"format": "json", "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%s" % VideoID}
url = "https://www.youtube.com/oembed"
query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
url = url + "?" + query_string

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    response_text = response.read()
    data = json.loads(response_text.decode())
    pprint.pprint(data)
    print(data['title'])
```

**example results:**

```
{'author_name': 'Google Developers',
 'author_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleDevelopers',
 'height': 270,
 'html': '<iframe width="480" height="270" '
         'src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SZj6rAYkYOg?feature=oembed" '
         'frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" '
         'allowfullscreen></iframe>',
 'provider_name': 'YouTube',
 'provider_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/',
 'thumbnail_height': 360,
 'thumbnail_url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SZj6rAYkYOg/hqdefault.jpg',
 'thumbnail_width': 480,
 'title': 'Google I/O 101:  Google APIs: Getting Started Quickly',
 'type': 'video',
 'version': '1.0',
 'width': 480}
Google I/O 101:  Google APIs: Getting Started Quickly
```

**2) Using Google API - required APIKEY**

```
import urllib.request
import json
import urllib
import pprint

APIKEY = "YOUR_GOOGLE_APIKEY"
VideoID = "YOUR_VIDEO_ID"

params = {'id': VideoID, 'key': APIKEY,
          'fields': 'items(id,snippet(channelId,title,categoryId),statistics)',
          'part': 'snippet,statistics'}

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos'

query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
url = url + "?" + query_string

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    response_text = response.read()
    data = json.loads(response_text.decode())
    pprint.pprint(data)
    print("TITLE: %s " % data['items'][0]['snippet']['title'])
```

**example results:**

```
{'items': [{'id': 'SZj6rAYkYOg',
            'snippet': {'categoryId': '28',
                        'channelId': 'UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw',
                        'title': 'Google I/O 101:  Google APIs: Getting '
                                 'Started Quickly'},
            'statistics': {'commentCount': '36',
                           'dislikeCount': '20',
                           'favoriteCount': '0',
                           'likeCount': '418',
                           'viewCount': '65783'}}]}
TITLE: Google I/O 101:  Google APIs: Getting Started Quickly
```

Answer (score 9):

Using JavaScript data API:

```
var loadInfo = function (videoId) {
    var gdata = document.createElement("script");
    gdata.src = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoId + "?v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=storeInfo";
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.appendChild(gdata);
};

var storeInfo = function (info) {
    console.log(info.data.title);
};
```

Then you just need to call `loadInfo(videoId)`.

More informations are available on the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json).

Comment: YouTube shut down the old APIs. Take a look here for more info about the new version https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started.

Answer (score 8):

One way to do this would be to retrieve the video from youtube as shown [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries.html)

Then extract the title out of the atom feed sent by youtube.  A sample feed is shown [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_understanding_video_feeds.html#Understanding_Feeds_and_Entries)

Answer (score 6):

I'll lay out the process as outlined by the [YouTube API v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started).

1. Make a / **login to the Google account** that you want to be associated with your YouTube API use.
2. **Create a new project** at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials.

   - On the upper left, next to the Google APIs logo, go to **Select a project** and **Create project** <kbd>+</kbd>.
   - **Wait** a moment for the creation to finish.
3. **Make a new API key**. You'll need it to access video info under v3.

   - If you're not already there, go to Credentials under the navigator on the left hand side, **APIs and Services > Credentials**.
   - Under the Credentials tab, click **Create Credentials** and select **API key**.
   - **Copy the API key** to your clipboard.
4. *Providing a video ID and your newly created API key*, go to this link to see your work in action: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=<YOUR VIDEO ID HERE>&key=<YOUR API KEY HERE>%20&part=snippet` (no angle brackets)

   - For more info on what you can access, see here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#partial. For convenience, I'll copy one of their examples here (Example 4). The `fields` and `part` parameters in the URL are key here.

---

## Example

The `URL` is, well, what URL you can go to through your browser to check it out. In return, you should get what's under `API response:`.

```
URL: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&key=YOUR_API_KEY
     &fields=items(id,snippet(channelId,title,categoryId),statistics)&part=snippet,statistics

Description: This example modifies the fields parameter from example 3
             so that in the API response, each video resource's snippet
             object only includes the channelId, title,
             and categoryId properties.

API response:

{
 "videos": [
  {
   "id": "7lCDEYXw3mM",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
    "title": "Google I/O 101: Q&A On Using Google APIs",
    "categoryId": "28"
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "3057",
    "likeCount": "25",
    "dislikeCount": "0",
    "favoriteCount": "17",
    "commentCount": "12"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

---

This gives you video info in the `.json` file format. If your project is to access this info through JavaScript, you may be going here next: [How to get JSON from URL in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970894/5708812).

Answer (score 5):

I believe the best way is to use youTube's gdata, and then grab info from XML that is returned

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/6_Ukfpsb8RI

Update:
There is a newer API out now which you should use instead

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

```
URL: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&key=YOUR_API_KEY
     &fields=items(id,snippet(channelId,title,categoryId),statistics)&part=snippet,statistics

Description: This example modifies the fields parameter from example 3 so that in the API response, each video resource's snippet object only includes the channelId, title, and categoryId properties.

API response:

{
 "videos": [
  {
   "id": "7lCDEYXw3mM",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
    "title": "Google I/O 101: Q&A On Using Google APIs",
    "categoryId": "28"
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "3057",
    "likeCount": "25",
    "dislikeCount": "0",
    "favoriteCount": "17",
    "commentCount": "12"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With bash, wget and lynx:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -e -p "Youtube address? " address
page=$(wget "$address" -O - 2>/dev/null)
title=$(echo "$page" | grep "   - ")
title="$(lynx --dump -force-html <(echo "<html><body>
$title
</body></html>")| grep "  - ")"
title="${title/*   - /}"
echo "$title"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// This is the youtube video URL: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOHHta68DdU
$code = "nOHHta68DdU";
// Get video feed info (xml) from youtube, but only the title | http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
$video_feed = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&q=".$code."&max-results=1&fields=entry(title)&prettyprint=true");
// xml to object | http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php
$video_obj = simplexml_load_string($video_feed);
// Get the title string to a variable
$video_str = $video_obj->entry->title;
// Output
echo $video_str;
```

Answer (score 3):

If python batch processing script is appreciated: I used **BeautifulSoup** to easily parse the title from HTML, **urllib** to download the HTML and **unicodecsv** libraries in order to save all the characters from Youtube title.

The only thing you need to do is to place csv with **single (named) column url** with URLs of the Youtube videos in the same folder as the script is and name it *yt-urls.csv* and run the script. You will get file *yt-urls-titles.csv* containing the URLs and its titles.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import unicodecsv as csv

with open('yt-urls-titles.csv', 'wb') as f:
    resultcsv = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter=';', quotechar='"',fieldnames=['url','title'])
    with open('yt-urls.csv', 'rb') as f:
        inputcsv = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
        resultcsv.writeheader()
        for row in inputcsv:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(row['url']).read(), "html.parser")
            resultcsv.writerow({'url': row['url'],'title': soup.title.string})
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have `youtube-dl`, it's as simple as:

```
youtube-dl --get-title https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some cut and paste code for ColdFusion:

http://trycf.com/gist/f296d14e456a7c925d23a1282daa0b90

It works on CF9 (and likely, earlier versions) using YouTube API v3, which requires an API key.

I left some comments and diag stuff in it, for anyone who wants to dig deeper. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can do using Json to get the all info about video

```
$jsonURL = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={Your_Video_ID_Here}&key={Your_API_KEY}8&part=snippet");
$json = json_decode($jsonURL);

$vtitle = $json->{'items'}[0]->{'snippet'}->{'title'};
$vdescription = $json->{'items'}[0]->{'snippet'}->{'description'};
$vvid = $json->{'items'}[0]->{'id'};
$vdate = $json->{'items'}[0]->{'snippet'}->{'publishedAt'};
$vthumb = $json->{'items'}[0]->{'snippet'}->{'thumbnails'}->{'high'}->{'url'};
```

I hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

using python i got it`import pafy url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMt47wvK6u0" video = pafy.new(url) print(video.title)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with java, try the Jsoup parser.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.youtube.com/ABDCEF").get();
document.title();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am getting name and url of each video in a playlist, you can modify this code as per your requirement.

```
$Playlist = ((Invoke-WebRequest "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKkRbc6W6NA&list=PLz9M61O0WZqSUvHzPHVVC4IcqA8qe5K3r&
index=1").Links | Where {$_.class -match "playlist-video"}).href
$Fname = ((Invoke-WebRequest "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKkRbc6W6NA&list=PLz9M61O0WZqSUvHzPHVVC4IcqA8qe5K3r&ind
ex=1").Links | Where {$_.class -match "playlist-video"}).outerText
$FinalText=""
For($i=0;$i -lt $playlist.Length;$i++)
{
Write-Output("'"+($Fname[$i].split("|")[0]).split("|")[0]+"'+"+"https://www.youtube.com"+$Playlist[$i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[JavaX](http://javax.tinybrain.de) now ships with this function. Showing a video's thumbnail and title, for example, is a two-liner:

```
SS map = youtubeVideoInfo("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4If_vFZdFTk"));
showImage(map.get("title"), loadImage(map.get("thumbnail_url")));
```

[Example](http://tinybrain.de/1011534)

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to Matej M, but more simply:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_video_name(id: str):
    """
    Return the name of the video as it appears on YouTube, given the video id.
    """
    r = requests.get(f'https://youtube.com/watch?v={id}')
    r.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    return soup.title.string


if __name__ == '__main__':
    js = get_video_name("RJqimlFcJsM")
    print('\n\n')
    print(js)
```

Answer (score 0):

I make a little bit of reinvention of [excellent Porto's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52664178/911419), and wrote this snippet on Python:

```
import urllib, urllib.request, json

input = "C:\\urls.txt"
output = "C:\\tracks.csv"

urls=[line.strip() for line in open(input)]
for url in urls:
    ID = url.split('=')
    VideoID = ID[1]
    params = {"format": "json", "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%s" % VideoID}
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/oembed"
    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
    url = url + "?" + query_string
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        response_text = response.read()
        try:
            data = json.loads(response_text.decode())
        except ValueError as e:
            continue # skip faulty url
        if data is not None:
            author = data['author_name'].split(' - ')
            author = author[0].rstrip()
            f = open(output, "a", encoding='utf-8')
            print(author, ',', data['title'], sep="", file=f)
```

It eats a plain text file with Youtube URL list:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_Vfgdfgg
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RndfgdfN8
...
```

and returns a CSV file with Artist-Title pairs:

```
Beyonce,Pretty hurts
Justin Timberlake,Cry me a river
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two modules that can help you which is **pafy** & y**outube-dl**. First install this module using pip. Pafy is using youtube-dl in the background to fetch the video information, you can also download videos using pafy and youtube-dl.

```
pip install youtube_dl
pip install pafy
```

Now you need to follow this code, I assume that you have the URL of any youtube video.

```
import pafy

def fetch_yt_video(link):
    video = pafy.new(link)
    print('Video Title is: ',video.title)

fetch_yt_video('https://youtu.be/CLUsplI4xMU')
```

The output is

```
Video Title is:  Make the perfect resume | For freshers & experienced | Step by step tutorial with free format
```