# Fetching YouTube video title from known video id

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I want to fetch a YouTube video title when the video id is known, using JavaScript only. Is it possible?

Comment: I thought the OP already has the video id and wants to fetch the *title* of the video (like, id is "099pb2c9pyg139p" and title is "Look at my funny cat").

Comment: hmm .. I already have video id.. I want to fetch video title...

Comment: We have this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216029/get-title-from-youtube-videos

Comment: We have this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216029/get-title-from-youtube-videos

Comment: I have checked those likes .. no help.. I want to do this using JS only.

Comment: Still a dupe of a dupe of a dupe :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using Javascript and JSON.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries

See: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json

So you do it like this:

```
<script 
type="text/javascript" 
src="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/videoid?v=2&alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=getTitle">
</script>
```

And then:

```
function getTitle(data) {
 var feed = data.feed;
 var entries = feed.entry || [];
  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
   var entry = entries[i];
   var title = entry.title.$t;
  }
 }
```