# Print youtube video title script with just video ID provided

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I'm doing a simple (not so simple for me) youtube BBCode that hides the embedded video in a dropdown, for when there's too many embedded videos, to not cause the web browser to lag trying to load them all at the same time.

I want the dropdown to display the video thumbnail (got that sorted) and title.

I don't know much about javascript, and the other questions and answers about this haven't worked for me. Example:[Fetching YouTube video title from known video id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596745/fetching-youtube-video-title-from-known-video-id) Maybe I don't know how to implement it.

**I just need the script to get the youtube vide title from the id and print it, really.**

Comment: What errors have you run into while trying the other methods you linked?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to check for those errors. I've just copy pasted them with just editing the initial var id so it uses the id provided by the poster.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19623573/2234742) might be helpful in learning how to check for JavaScript errors.

Comment: To query the youtube API, I believe you have to register the application and use the key given. The old API would allow anyone to query but as far as i'm aware, they have removed it pushing people to use the V3 API.

Comment: Here's a link to the 2.0 API you're trying to use. https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries **The YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated as of March 4, 2014.** The correct API to use is this one. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript I hope this helps you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching YouTube video title from known video id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596745/fetching-youtube-video-title-from-known-video-id)

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596745/fetching-youtube-video-title-from-known-video-id/10597710

Answer (score 1):

Edit: YouTube shut down the v2 API in 2015, take a look at the documentation of the new API v3 for a working code.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30685729/753676

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10597710/753676

You can do this with plain JavaScript like this:

```
<script 
type="text/javascript" 
src="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/videoid?v=2&alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=getTitle">
</script>
```

And then:

```
function getTitle(data) {
 var feed = data.feed;
 var entries = feed.entry || [];
  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
   var entry = entries[i];
   var title = entry.title.$t;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, since version 3. This is no longer possible with the youtube API without auth.

You can use [noembed](http://noembed.com) however without Auth if you want to grab basic info about the video.

I.E http://noembed.com/embed?url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DbDOYN-6gdRE&callback=my_embed_function

The response is JSON.