# XMLHttpRequest module not defined/found

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

This is my code:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "//URL")
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Basic //AuthKey");
xhr.send();
```

I am getting the error:

```
Cannot find module 'xmlhttprequest'
```

When I remove the first line, I am getting:

```
XMLHttpRequest is not defined
```

I have searched all over and people have mentioned a problem with Node.js here and there but my installation of Node was correct so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest is a built-in object in *web browsers*.

It is not distributed with Node. [The http module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) is the built-in tool for making HTTP requests from Node.

Most people making HTTP requests from node use a third party library with a friendlier API. Two popular choices are [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) (for use both in Node.js and browsers) and [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) (which implements the fetch API which is built into browsers and is a modern replacement for XMLHttpRequest.

*2022 update*: Node 18 has a native implementation of `fetch` [enabled by default](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce/#fetch-experimental).

If you really want to use XHR in Node.js then there are a couple of third party implementations. [`xmlhttprequest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest) (which seems to be unmaintained) and [`xhr2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xhr2) (which had an update when I added it to this answer but seems to have been abandoned by the developer since).

1. Install it with npm,

   ```
    npm install xhr2
   ```
2. Now you can `require` it in your code.

   ```
    var XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   ```

Answer (score 32):

Since the last update of the [xmlhttprequest module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest) was around [2 years ago](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest/commit/master), in some cases it does not work as expected.

So instead, you can use the [xhr2 module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xhr2). In other words:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

becomes:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

But ... of course, there are more popular modules like [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), because -for example- uses promises:

```
// Make a request for a user with a given ID
axios.get('/user?ID=12345').then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 13):

With the [xhr2 library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xhr2) you can globally overwrite `XMLHttpRequest` from your JS code. This allows you to use external libraries in node, that were intended to be run from browsers / assume they are run in a browser.

```js
global.XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
```