# XMLHttpRequest not defined when using JSONLoader in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js

I'm writing a game in Three.js, and as a multiplayer game, I need to verify client positions serverside to prevent cheating. I'm currently trying to load a model on the server, as such:

```
var THREE = require("three");
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( './models/tree.json', function ( geometry, materials ) {
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
    res.send(mesh);
});
```

However, the server dies and spits out

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
    at FileLoader.load
```

This request is coming at `node_modules\three\build\three.js:29258`, where an `XMLHttpRequest` is made.

Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong, or is this portion of Three.js broken for Node?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three.js uses an [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to load files such as your JSON file. `XMLHttpRequest` is built-in in browsers environments, but it's not built-in in a Node environment, so it's not defined, thus the error. You'll have to install the [`xmlhttprequest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest) package through NPM to use it with Node.

Since Three.js does not require the `xmlhttprequest` module, you're going to have to set a global variable so that `new XMLHttpRequest` will work:

```
global.XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest");
```

Comment: I have posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46081151/2954267) about why to not use in all cases the `xmlhttprequest module`. You should check it out.