# Webpack + Karma + Mocha: How do I use real XmlHttpRequest in Mocha tests?

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, karma-runner, jsdom, karma-mocha

## Problem

I'm trying to test TypeScript code that uses `XMLHttpRequest`. When running **the whole Karma test suite** from the IDE, the test **passes** because it opens a browser and gets the `XmlHttpRequest` and DOM libraries provided. For reference, here is the Karma run command:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/js-karma/js_reporter/karma-intellij/lib/intellijServer.js --karmaPackageDir=/Users/user/project/node_modules/karma --configFile=/Users/user/project/karma.conf.js
```

... However, when running the test **individually** (by right-clicking the test and selecting 'run' on it in the WebStorm IDE), it **fails** with the message `ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined` because Mocha is not set up to open a browser (and thus is not provided with the `XmlHttpRequest` or DOM libraries). For reference, this Mocha command is:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/user/project/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --require ts-node/register --ui bdd --reporter /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/NodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js /Users/user/project/tests/test.ts --grep "XHR "
```

I can provide the `xmlhttprequest` library, but Mocha then complains `ReferenceError: document is not defined` because it lacks a DOM library - here, I think I need to provide something like `jsdom` and/or `mocha-jsdom` or get Mocha to run its tests in a browser (whether Firefox or a headless browser like PhantomJS). However, after many hours of trying, I conclude that I can't figure out how.

Given my current project setup, how can I run my individual Mocha tests using real XHR?

---

## Project files

Most likely only `karma.conf.js` needs changing, but I have included them all for completeness.

### `test.ts`

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
// import {jsdom} from 'jsdom'; // mocha-jsdom?

describe("XHR", () => {
    it("Test should not fail upon XHR.", function(){
        new XMLHttpRequest();
    });
});
```

### `karma.conf.js`

```
var path = require("path");
var webpackConfig = require("./webpack.config");

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        autoWatch: true,
        basePath: "",
        client: {
            mocha: {
                reporter: 'html'
                // require: [require.resolve('jsdom_setup.js')]
            }
        },
        browsers: ["Firefox"],
        colors: true,
        exclude: [],
        files: [
            "tests/test.ts"
        ],
        frameworks: ["mocha", "chai"],
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        plugins: [
            "karma-*"
            // "jsdom"
            // "mocha-jsdom"
        ],
        port: 9876,
        preprocessors: {
            "*.ts": ["webpack"]
        },
        reporters: ["mocha"],
        singleRun: false,
        webpack: {
            module: webpackConfig.module,
            resolve: webpackConfig.resolve
        }
    });
};
```

### `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "despair",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --display-error-details",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^3.4.35",
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.40",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "jsdom": "^9.12.0",
    "karma": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.2",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.2",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.1.5",
    "watch": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0-rc.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

### `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "watch": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es3",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "outDir": "./build",
        "allowJs": true,
        "types": ["mocha", "chai"] // Note: implicit in TypeScript 2
    }
}
```

### `webpack.config.js`

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    /* Output bundle name : entry point */
    entry:  {
        "./build/Entry" : "./src/Entry.ts"
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        libraryTarget: 'this'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        modules: [".", "node_modules"],
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader"
            } 
        ]
    }
    , plugins: []
};
```

Comment: you dont....mocha is nodejs, not native js. I would look into using libraries like request,http, or request-promise to do api/async requests. Any browser-side testing, i would recommend checking out protractor, and click elements that invoke xmlhttprequests. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604460/xmlhttprequest-module-not-defined-found