# Getting JavaScript error in a JSON operation

Tags: javascript, json

[image: My code sample]

I checked so many websites and followed their examples, and they all just do the same:

```
let chr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

For some reason I get the above error!

Comment: Please paste the code / error messages directly instead of supplying an image. Perhaps [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604460/xmlhttprequest-module-not-defined-found) will help.

Comment: I guess the examples you read are targeted for browsers and you execute the code in nodejs.

Comment: It's XML, not CML
`let chr = new XMLHttpRequest()`

Please check that you wrote the write method name there.

Comment: please take the time to format your post correctly. How are we going to copy/paste code into our own IDE from a picture?

Comment: Yeah that's my bad, first time actually asking a question myself on this site!

Comment: You can (and should) still repair this question. Please take the error and paste in it by editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js does not come natively with XHR like browsers. Perhaps you should try using the built in [http.request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback).

There is also a node module called [xmlhttprequest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest) that you can use which will make your code work without changing much of it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the forum..!

You are getting an error as you are trying to run XMLHttpRequest as an browser style. To run this in nodejs, you need the following package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest

Here is the usage that how you can include it in NodeJS.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest#usage

Comment: I just installed the npm xlmhttprequest, but it did not seem to help, so I did this instead:
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
which seemed to work, thanks for the help mate !

Comment: Great! Enjoy Coding