# XMLHttpRequest error for api call module not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

Here is my code:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open("GET", "data.json", true); // not working

request.onload = function() {
  // begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response);

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].name + " is a " + data[i].race + ".");
  }
};

request.send();
```

I run node json.js and it stops right at the first line and gives me XMLHttpRequest is not defined. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest module not defined/found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604460/xmlhttprequest-module-not-defined-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest is a [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). You need to use the `node.js` framework, which defines the [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) API which you can use for web requests.

There are also plenty of [other frameworks](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html) that can help you out:

- [request](https://github.com/request/request)
- [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)
- [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent)
- [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got)
- [xmlhttprequest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest)