# Cannot find module 'xhr2'

Tags: javascript, json

PFB snippet :

```
let XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'data.json', true);
xhr.send();
```

Error :
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'xhr2'

I have installed : npm install xmlhttprequest
But I still keep getting this error.

Comment: How is `xhr2` related to `xmlhttprequest`? Why do you install `xmlhttprequest` when you want to use `xhr2`? Have you tried `npm i xhr2`?

Comment: I did that, but it gives me another error : throw new NetworkError(`Unsupported protocol ${this._url.protocol}`);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604460/xmlhttprequest-module-not-defined-found

Comment: You can either install `npm i xmlhttprequest` and use it with `let XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest');` or install `npm i xhr2` and use it with `let XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');`

Comment: _"I did that, but it gives me another error : `throw new NetworkError(Unsupported protocol ${this._url.protocol});`"_ That's a new, unrelated question.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's telling you that 'xhr2' is not installed, so might as well try `npm i xhr2`

Srry I would comment but don't have enough reputation or whatever

Comment: I tried it and still doesn't work. I followed : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604460/xmlhttprequest-module-not-defined-found