# How to create json file with an array created in cmd running js project?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, puppeteer

Im working in a puppeteer js scrapping project that is running in Windows terminal "node file.js". I get an array as my scrapping result, but now I need to use it in php. I need to make a file for php to read or to send the data directly to my php file.

Any ideas?

I have tried AJAX but I get this: ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined

Also I have tried to create the file in my js project using:

```
new File([provincias], "xScrap.json", { type: "application/json" });
```

and getting this result:
ReferenceError: File is not defined

Answer (score 0):

For why there is an error of `ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest` it is for web browsers, and node js has another way of creating HTTP requests:
[XMLHttpRequest module not defined/found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604460/xmlhttprequest-module-not-defined-found)

To send or request data to your PHP file or server, you need to create HTTP requests. I personally suggest using Axios, but there are a lot of alternatives here:
[How is an HTTP POST request made in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-is-an-http-post-request-made-in-node-js)

As for your creation of file error, I don't know why it isn't working, but I'll suggest using the fs module to create/read/update/delete files in node js: https://blog.risingstack.com/fs-module-in-node-js/