# Write JSON Data to Variable

Tags: javascript, json, weather

I am working on a project where I need to write weather data to a variable. (URL = http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=96950,us&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0) How can I get the temperature in the area?

Comment: This will help point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460378/how-to-get-json-from-url

Comment: you can start here... (assuming that you're using Javascript to read the JSON) http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_files.asp

Answer (score 1):

In the following code `<url>` represent your `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=96950,us&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0` url in string format.

Use this code to use the data JSON from an URL with Vanilla JS (no framework):

```
/**
 * The function to reach JSON data from an `<url>`
 * function getJSON
 * @param {string}   url  - The string url we want to reach to obtain an object JSON from an url.
 * @param {function} next - What you want do after obtain the JSON data. See after.
 */
function getJSON(url, next) {

    // Create an object to perform an AJAX call.
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Declare what method you will use, to what url, and if the rest of code will wait the response (false) or if this call will be async (true).
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    // Perform the request.
    request.send();

    // What we want to do if the url is correctly reached.
    request.addEventListener("load", function () {
        // The data are invalid if this condition of status is respected.
        if (request.status < 200 && request.status >= 400) {
            // return is used to stop the execution of script and return the effective error.
            return next(new Error("We reached our target server, but it returned an error."));
        }

        /**
         * All is fine. Use the next() callback.
         * @callback next
         * @memberOf getJSON~
         * @param {null|Object}      err  - null if no error occur, a `new Error()` object if an error occured.
         * @param {object|undefined} data - Only in case of success, the data we want obtain from url to JSON format.
         */
        next(null, JSON.parse(request.responseText));
    });

    // What we want to do if an error occured.
    request.addEventListener("error", function () {
        // An error is occured, send this error.
        next(new Error("There was a connection error of some sort."));
    });
}

/* Use the previous declared function with real string url in place of `<url>` */
getJSON(<url>, function (err, data) {
    // In case of errror...
    if (err) {
      // ...We will return a message for example
      return err;
    }

    // Or in success case, use data !
    data;
});
```

Or simly use `XMLHttpRequest()` in other way [here a JavaScript explaination for this function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Same code with jQuery:

```
function getJSON(url, next) {
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
      next(null, data);
    }).error(function () {
      next(new Error("There was a connection error of some sort."));
    });
}
getJSON(<url>, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return err;
    }
    data;
});
```

Or simply use `$.getJSON()`: [here API explaination for this function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Comment: Just posting code is not very useful for a beginner. Please explain your solution.

Comment: I will add some comment so.

Comment: For your information, Felix, I am a kid learning. I know some things, but JSON reading is not in my skill list.