# When using mustache.js, how do I render my templates from a data url, not just a local file?

Tags: javascript, json, templates, terminal, mustache

I understand how to take a mustache template and from a .json file on my local drive run something like `mustache index.json project.mustache > test.html` to get a static html file I can then use with all my templated content. But how do I replace `index.json` with say a data feed url like `http://test.ookb.co/index.json`? to make it easy to render updated files?

Comment: See here regarding retrieving JSON from URL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460378/how-to-get-json-from-url-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks. However, my problem isn't getting the JSON its actually feeding it to mustache to then render into static HTML files — the instructions are easy for files or for arrays you just write into the JS... I just can't figure out how to request the json feed url in the terminal instead of a local file