# My heartbeat is not pausing for Timeout value

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a few large forms that are causing problems with filling them out before the session times out.  I need a little javascript to include at the end of the page to ping a file every few minutes to refresh the session timeout for as long as the page is open.  So I have a function that the last statement is to call the function again after a gap.  Also, for a range of reasons jQuery and other frameworks are not available for this.  So I have put this together from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970894/385011

```
var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("get", url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "json";
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var status = xhr.status;
        if (status == 200) {
            callback(null, xhr.response);
        } else {
            callback(status);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
};

//hearbeat 
function heartbeat(heartbeaturl){
    getJSON(heartbeaturl,function(err, data) {
        console.log(Date.now());
        console.log(data.time);
        setTimeout(heartbeat(heartbeaturl), data.time);
    });
}

console.log("run heartbeat");
heartbeat("heartbeat.json")
```

data.time is returning 60000 so it should run heartbeat every minute but it sin running every 1~4ms.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats the "setTimeout problem". People forget about what setTimeout does:

```
function setTimeout(func){
//wait
func();
}
```

So you need to pass a function to set Timeout. What you actually do is: you pass **the result of the function** :
What you do:

```
setTimeout(func(parameter),1000);
```

What you want to do:

```
setTimeout(func,1000);
```

But how to pass the parameter? Thats easy:

```
setTimeout(function(){func(parameter)},1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout(heartbeat(heartbeaturl), data.time);
```

Should be something as:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    heartbeat(heartbeaturl);
}, data.time)
```

As otherwise `heartbeat(heartbeaturl)` is executed immediately without waiting for data.time to be reached.

Comment: Akternative to creating a new anonymous function is to pass the parameters the to `setTimeout` like so - `setTimeout(heartbeat, data.time, heartbeaturl)`. Anything after the delay will be passed onto the delayed function when it gets executed.