# How to Parse JSON from a web api in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing

I am trying to parse this HummingBird api with sample url : 
            http://hummingbird.me/api/v1/search/anime?query=naruto

However, I do not know how to get each id seperately , or each name seperately. For e.g:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>

  <h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = //make this display name

  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

I want the demo element to display the title of the first one in the list. Can anyone tell me how I can possibly do this?

Comment: are you talking about splitting the `?query=naruto` into `{"query": "naruto"}`?

Comment: are you looking for JSON.parse ???

Comment: No, for e.g in the url there is the JSON : 

    [  
   {  
      "id":11,
      "mal_id":20,
      "slug":"naruto",
      "status":"Finished Airing",
      "url":"https://hummingbird.me/anime/naruto",
      "title":"Naruto",
      "alternate_title":"",
      "episode_count":220,
      "episode_length":23,

and so on and I want to get the title of this one or the episode count in the demo

Comment: Possibly JSON.parse but an example for a url based JSON would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read an external local JSON file in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery below is the snippet you can use.

```
var results = "";
$.get("http://hummingbird.me/api/v1/search/anime?query=naruto",function(data){
  results = JSON.parse(data);
});
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Should this be in the $(document).ready......... {} thing? also how can i for e.g get something specific ffrom the result like just the episode-count?

Comment: You must know the basics of JSON in JavaScript to accomplish this.  You can use Google to find documentation for this. http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: this can also be accomplished with `jQuery.getJSON()` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: Depends on where you are calling it, if you are using at page load then defiantly $(document).ready should come but if it depends on another ajax call then inside that call. For getting just the count  you will need to loop though the results and construct the required result set like below. 
var objecter = []
$.each(results,function(index,value){
  objecter.push(value.[required_key])
});

Answer (score 1):

1. Download JQuery from [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js) and put the file next to your html.
2. Add this element between the `html` tag and the `body`

```html
<head>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

3. Replace `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =` with:

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
                $.getJSON("http://hummingbird.me/api/v1/search/anime?query=naruto", null, function (data) {document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data[0].title})
            })
```

JQuery is a JS library that makes life easy.
The function below takes 1 function as an argument and executes it after the page has loaded

```
$(document).ready()
```

The next function makes an HTTP GET request and parses the response to js object

```
$.getJSON("http://hummingbird.me/api/v1/search/anime?query=naruto", null,...)
```

The next function gets the title of the first element of `data`

```
function (data) {document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data[0].title}
```

Comment: I tried this but this did not work either :/ appreciate the detail tho

Answer (score 0):

mmm try this fiddle i don't know exactly how you read the file but if you get a string do the `JSON.parse(STRING)` before.

https://jsfiddle.net/79a1abbL/3/

Comment: Thanks that helps me understand a bit of the path to take

Comment: if you need to read the JSON from url try to see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460378/how-to-get-json-from-url-in-javascript