# How to access a JSON array directly from url

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to javascript and I have a Json Array in a url like below;

```
[{"year":2015,"month":4,"day":1,"num":0,"time":"2015-04-01","hour":0,"zone":3,"state1":2137,"state2":249,"state3":1810,"state4":30,"state5":0},....]
```

I want to access the state1 value and assign that value to the variable which I have.How can I do that?(Is parsing necessary or are there any methods there that we can directly access the JSON object in the URL).I am sorry if I asked anything wrong.

Comment: Use ajax to [load json from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460378/how-to-get-json-from-url-in-javascript), and parse the response using JSON.parse() method. If you are experiencing any problem with that let us know how did you write your code for that. We could help you correct it..

Comment: How do you get URL?

Comment: @guest271314 I retrieve it from a particular data source and keep it in that url.

Comment: @RKR Do you mean actual URL, or variable? The `javascript` array at Question is a not a `JSON` string.

Comment: @guest271314 Actual URL it will be like http://localhost:8080/dataurl. I want to access the data in the URL.I think getJSON is the required one

Comment: The array at Question is the expected result of request, yes?

Comment: @ guest271314 Yes Exactly

Comment: Have you tried `javascript` at Answer posted by @GautamKrishnaR ?

Comment: Thank you all .I tried with Sen Jacob's Answer using getJSON and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery [`getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function :

```
$.getJSON(' localhost:8080/dataurl', function(data) {
  //data is the JSON string
  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);    
});
```

Now, Below are the methods to parse the `jsonObj` to get the `state1`.

**Using array [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method :**

```js
var jsonObj = [
                {
                  "year":2015,
                  "month":4,
                  "day":1,
                  "num":0,
                  "time":"2015-04-01",
                  "hour":0,
                  "zone":3,
                  "state1":2137,
                  "state2":249,
                  "state3":1810,
                  "state4":30,
                  "state5":0
                },
                {
                  "year":2016,
                  "month":12,
                  "day":1,
                  "num":0,
                  "time":"2015-04-01",
                  "hour":0,
                  "zone":3,
                  "state1":2474,
                  "state2":250,
                  "state3":1811,
                  "state4":31,
                  "state5":0
                }
              ];

var state1arr = jsonObj.map(function(item) {
  return item.state1;
});

console.log(state1arr);
```

**using [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop :**

```js
var jsonObj = [
                {
                  "year":2015,
                  "month":4,
                  "day":1,
                  "num":0,
                  "time":"2015-04-01",
                  "hour":0,
                  "zone":3,
                  "state1":2137,
                  "state2":249,
                  "state3":1810,
                  "state4":30,
                  "state5":0
                },
                {
                  "year":2016,
                  "month":12,
                  "day":1,
                  "num":0,
                  "time":"2015-04-01",
                  "hour":0,
                  "zone":3,
                  "state1":2474,
                  "state2":250,
                  "state3":1811,
                  "state4":31,
                  "state5":0
                }
              ];

var state1arr = [];
for (var i in jsonObj) {
  state1arr.push(jsonObj[i].state1);
}

console.log(state1arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

The data you have is array of objects and you need to loop to access each object and access the key using dot notation

Like this,

```
var app=[{"year":2015,"month":4,"day":1,"num":0,"time":"2015-04-01","hour":0,"zone":3,"state1":2137,"state2":249,"state3":1810,"state4":30,"state5":0}];
for(var i of app)
{
console.log(i.state1);
}
```

Comment: You can simply access the JSON var in js just like using the javascript object variable. you need not have to use the loops.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following JS Code:

```
var getJSON = function(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
     if (status == 200) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
};
```

You can now use the function to get the JSON contents from the url:

```
getJSON("<URL>").then(function(data) { // Replace <URL> With your URL
    var jsondata = data.result; //store result in variable

    // Your code here....///
    ///  Now you can access the json's data using jsondata variable:  //
    // jsondata[0].year will have the value of year key, jsondata[0].month will have month key and so on.... //

}, function(status) { //error detection....
  alert('Something went wrong.');
});
```