# Pass local JSON to Vue.js in Django Wagtail CMS

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, wagtail

I have a python program that outputs and updates a json file. I would like to pass that json file to Vue.js. What is the convention for doing this? (I am using CDNs)

Django Fixture, ajax/getJson, vue-router fetch, something else?

Comment: Vue [recommends](https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html) the _promise based HTTP client_ named [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get JSON from URL in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460378/how-to-get-json-from-url-in-javascript)

Comment: I keep getting 404's for local files

Comment: You would need to show a [mcve]. All I can say is that a 404 error means the file is not found.

Comment: Got axios working. The error was in the url pattern...