# How do i retrieve data from json data

Tags: html, json

I am trying to get data of "value" from a data file

```
{"success":"true","value":"500","items":"12","currency":"NOK"}
```

this is what i think should work.

```
<div class="value"></div>
    <script>
    $.get('URLTOFILE', function(data) {


    var text = `Value: ${data.value|| "Not Found"}`       

        $(".value").html(text);

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: You can add the tag [tag:jquery] to your question. Also what is your problem exactly? Do you face an error? Did you try you snippet? Did you read the official [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get JSON from URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460378/how-to-get-json-from-url-in-javascript)

Comment: What exactly is the question here? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Can you post full, runnable code?

Answer (score 0):

Is your `json` file hosted on a server somewhere? If so, are you getting any errors when you attempt to fetch it?

If the `json` file is simply a file on your computer, you won't be able to load it like that. If you are using `webpack` or another package manager to bundle your files, you can use `import` to import the file into your javascript file like so:

```
import json from "file.json";

console.log("My json: ", json);

// Rest of javascript file here
```

This assumes that you've set up your bundler to handle `json` files though. Webpack does this for you automatically. So if you're using it, then this should work. Not sure about other bundlers though.

But it's best to host the file on a server and fetch it, especially if the data changes constantly - such as from an API.