# How to remove share and watch letter from embedded you-tube video?

Tags: youtube-api

Unable to hide share and watch letter icon from [embedded youtube-video](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en)?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to only remove the "watch later" and "share" buttons from youtube iframe embed player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373880/is-it-possible-to-only-remove-the-watch-later-and-share-buttons-from-youtube)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, since September 2018 there is no option to hide Watch Later, Share and Video Title within embedded YouTube iframe. Simply, YouTube does not allow anymore ‘clean’ embed w/o those components.