# Is it possible to remove the "Title" “Watch later” and “share” buttons from YouTube iframe embed player

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-iframe-api

How can I remove the Title, watch later and share buttons from YouTube iframe embed player.

Comment: One way to hide related videos **and other controls for that matter* is by disabling the css of YouTube (*like, remove this line from the generated YouTube video:* `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/yts/cssbin/www-player-webp-vflyjuSvx.css" name="www-player">`). as how you can do that, you have to investigate further.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to only remove the "watch later" and "share" buttons from youtube iframe embed player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373880/is-it-possible-to-only-remove-the-watch-later-and-share-buttons-from-youtube)

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove that buttons from original youtube embed player, but you can get rid of it by using https://plyr.io/