# Retrieve YouTube Video title using API (Python)?

Tags: python, youtube

These two inputs should have the same title:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAUa5RDUvO4

https://youtu.be/LAUa5RDUvO4

But I can't get both to work in one program, seemingly because the ID (in here, LAUa5RDUvO4) cannot be found for the shorturl.

How can I print the title using `Youtube API`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get title from YouTube videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216029/get-title-from-youtube-videos)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.
This isn't a free code writing service.
Neither is it a replacement for tutorials or web searches.
Please read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and add the code you've tried so far. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Comment: edited, sorry for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this code to get the video title. All you need is just video id. This question already has an answer [Get title from YouTube videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216029/get-title-from-youtube-videos) . Hope question gets duplicated. The below answer is by porto which I find to be useful.

```
import urllib.request
import json
import urllib

#change to yours VideoID or change url inparams
VideoID = "LAUa5RDUvO4" 

params = {"format": "json", "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%s" % VideoID}
url = "https://www.youtube.com/oembed"
query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
url = url + "?" + query_string

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    response_text = response.read()
    data = json.loads(response_text.decode())
    print(data['title'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply - however, I ran this, and it also prints the video resolution and the specs of the video. is there a way to only print the title?

Comment: Now you may try. It only prints title.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **lxml** parser and **xpath** expressions to extract the title of a youtube video

```
import lxml
from lxml import etree
youtube = etree.HTML(urllib.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQEOBZLx-Z8").read()) //enter your youtube url here
video_title = youtube.xpath("//span[@id='eow-title']/@title") //get xpath using firepath firefox addon
print ''.join(video_title)
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not looking to use lxml at the moment but this definitely helps!